# How do you monitor your HP hardware while running virtual servers?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

Our organization servers are mostly not virtualized and we have been using HP System Management, System insight manager to get hardware health from the servers. This system works well and we like it.

However, times, she are a changin' and More and more of our OS's are being virtualised. Is there HP System management tool that can run in the guest that can report on the physical servers health and status? Like if the RAID has gone suspect of one of the UPS is going bad?

Vmware Esxi 5
HP Proliant G7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using the HP-specific builds of VMWare ESXi *or* adding the HP offline bundle to your existing ESXi installations. The [full set of drivers/utilities](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4141%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for your generation of server and VMWare version are [here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=swEnvOID%253D4141%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

The main thing you'll need is the [HP offline bundle](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_e384704b3a2942478d2e1f4692%257CswEnvOID%253D4141%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), which will provide a few more health agents than you have now, and will include disk and array status (ESXi does not provide this by default).

The other helpful package is the [HP offline utilities package](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=4091432&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_5d50e5456b714656a4ca4bea78%257CswEnvOID%253D4141%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken), which gives you `hpacucli` (CLI array management) and `hponcfg` (CLI ILO management).

From there, you can set standard alerts in the vCenter setup under the "Hardware Health" category. It's a nice umbrella, since power supply, fan status, temperature, disk and even ILO status will report. vCenter uses SNMP traps by default, but it is easy to also add email alerts.

See:
[Configuring vCenter alarm for loss of psu redudancy](https://serverfault.com/questions/436858/configuring-vcenter-alarm-for-loss-of-psu-redudancy/437374#437374)

and
[How to find out more hardware details using only ESXi4.1 and (possibly) shell](https://serverfault.com/questions/313843/how-to-find-out-more-hardware-details-using-only-esxi4-1-and-possibly-shell)

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't even aware there was a HP specific build of ESXi. Theres so much good information here.

Comment: Note: the HP-specific build is handy, but these days, you're better off using normal ESXi and downloading the agents I linked. Same result.

Answer (score 2):

HP System Insight Manager support also WMware Esxi managed systems as reported in the support matrix http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c03341309/c03341309.pdf
If you like SIM you can continue to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In the VSphere client click on the hardware status tab. You can see all the insight information. Also you can configure alarms via VCenter for status info off these.

Also if you go into Configuration --> Power Management and click on properties you can set the iLO details for power management.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend against using the HP image. I had many instances of issues with them, latest one being not able to apply a license because HP made the license area on their install read-only ([link](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?locale=en_US&objectID=c03005742)). vmware Vanilla install + offline bundle works wonders.

Comment: Did you even read the question?